# De repente al abrir android studio me di cuenta de que esta en otro idioma y no lo entiendo, ¿tienen idea del por que sucede eso?

Tags: android-studio

No se entiende las letras
todo se cambio como de idioma
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: buscaste algun tutorial que te de atajos de teclado para llegar a la opcion de idiomas?

Comment: no,pero ahora busco

Comment: alguien puede ayudarme? aun sigo con el problema